# Is it good style in TypeScript to prefix type names with "T" and interface names with "I"?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Maybe that's mostly a matter of taste, but I'm really interested in different opinons about the following (any opinion is very welcome):

What about prefixing TypeScript types with "T" and interfaces with "I" (sometimes this is done by Microsoft that way)? Why good idea? Why bad idea?

Examples:

```
interface IPerson {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string
}

type TDirection = 'up' | 'down'
```

And what about prefixing enum names?

Comment: Coding style is really a matter of opinion and what the team members consider readable, independent of the language. That's why most larger project have some kind of coding style guideline, which can vastly differ; for example, compare the [GNU styleguide](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html) with the [Linux kernel styleguide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html).

Comment: > "First off, I’d suggest printing out a copy of the GNU coding standards, and NOT read it. Burn them, it’s a great symbolic gesture.", from Linux Kernel Styleguide lol